# ExtJS 4 Load store (just array) for a combo inside a grid using renderer

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

I've been facing an issue on ExtJS while developing a UI:

I have a simple array which contains:

```
['1234','2345','3456']
```

I created a grid which loads some data, one of the columns in that grid should contain a combobox, which I already done by:

```
this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
            clicksToEdit: 1
        });
```

I have the editor with an empty store:

```
{text: "Tickets", renderer: Utils.renderCombo, dataIndex: 'ASSOC_TKT_NUMS', flex: 1,
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                    editable: false,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    store: []
                }) 
        },
```

And on my method "renderCombo" I'm doing this, since I need to render my array in the store (which at first uses a [] as you can see above) :

```
renderCombo: function(value, meta, record) {
 meta.column.editor.getStore().loadData(value);
}
```

But that does not seems to work, I even see my column empty, not a combobox.

Is there something I'm missing or something I need to change in my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

When you specify, that this column's editor field will be combobox, first of all you need to create Cell Editor and only then specify edit field

```
editor: Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
   field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                editable: false,
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: []
            }) 
})
```